# Vale a pena medir desempenho entre aplicação Java x Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, desempenho, kotlin

Mexendo na documentação da Google Developers, achei algo bem bacana como:
[Medir o desempenho do aplicativo com o Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

Mas ao saber que Java e Kotlin são interpretados pela JVM, acredito eu que a diferença de desempenho não seja tão grande, pois pelo que vi entre as linguagens, quando o assunto é velocidade, eles levam em relação a escrita (Programação Funcional) por ser mais rápido que acaba acelerando o desenvolvimento da aplicação.

Com isso, alguém aqui já passou por essa e chegou a realizar esses tipos de medidas (CPU, Memoria)?

Comment: Não tenho certeza mas acredito que seja isso mesmo, como ambas linguagens são compiladas para bytecode (por isso as duas podem ser usadas juntas) não há, ou pelo menos quase, diferença de performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha opinião pessoal, como um usuário muito forte de Java por toda a minha carreira como programador, que hoje migrou para quase 100% Kotlin:

**Não há diferença significativa de performance**. Não possuo dados para comprovar isso, no entanto, aplicativos **Android** programados em Java que foram convertidos para Kotlin **sem pensar em performance**, simplesmente reescrevendo código para o idioma mais Kotlinístico funcionaram perfeitamente da mesma forma.

### Além disso:

Não há necessidade de se preocupar tanto com performance, a não ser que esta seja um impeditivo. Via de regra, um usuário não vai nem perceber que a tela carregou em 1 segundo, e não em 0.6667 segundo (opção mais performática possível). Ou que seu algorítimo completo, que não é crítico em performance, levou um segundo a mais.

**Não otimize seu código prematuramente**. Se você não tem problemas com performance, e se seu código não será crítico em performance, não precisa pensar na diferença performática.

Answer (score 3):

Medir performance é sempre interessante quando está percebendo que deveria ser mais rápido. E a performance muda dependendo de uma série de fatores. O mesmo código pode dar diferenças.

Uma quantidade considerável de bibliotecas de Kotlin são diferentes das usadas em Java. Escrever o código de uma determinada forma em Java e reproduzir em Kotlin pode causar um problema de performance já que são filosofias diferentes, com compiladores bem diferentes.

É claro que na maioria dos casos terá pouca diferença, mas tem casos que não. Ou seja, só medindo para ver :)

Não sei o que quis dizer com programação funcional, Kotlin tem bem pouco, só um tiquinho a mais que Java, mas isto pode ajudar na performance em alguns pontos e ser ruim em outros.

Comment: "[...] quando o assunto é velocidade, eles levam em relação a escrita (Programação Funcional) [...]" porque pelo que vi, Kotlin tenta trazer mais pro programador o costume de usar funções lambdas etc.

Comment: Isso é só um ponto do paradigma, e pouco importante, e Java tem tb e usa cada vez mais. Pra nossa sorte não uis ter antes, assim nasceu o C#.